# How can i get an index of a string as an int?

Tags: java, string

I create an integer and I have to print out the values backwards. So if my number is 12345, it has to print:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

The numbers have to be on a separate line:

```
System.out.println(number.nextDigit());
```

Each with a method `nextDigit();` which returns the next number from the last and it must return an integer not a char or a string.

Any help?

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/xrpKZixE

Comment: Is this homework? **TAG** What did you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike strings that may consist of multiple characters, `int`s represent a single number.

The trick to solving this problem with `int`s is applying `%` and `/` operators: by taking `num % 10`, you get the last digit; by taking `num / 10`, you chop the last digit off.

```
while (num != 0) {
    int lastDigit = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    System.out.println(lastDigit);
}
```

Comment: Yea but it doesnt return the numbers backwards

Comment: @domingocool no, it's an `int` (take a look at the link from my prior comment).

Comment: Ok well if i put it in a method, would it retrun lastDigit?

Comment: @domingocool You can make a method that does it. Of course you'd need to remove the `while` loop, make `num` an instance variable, and replace printing with `return`.

Comment: How do I do it? Im sorry but its very hard

Comment: @domingocool You are pretty close there: drop variable `last` and  `l` variables, and change the `next` method slightly ([link](http://pastebin.com/S9qcbNzW)).

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to convert to a String, and go from there:

```
String digits = String.valueOf(number);
char thirdDigit = digits.charAt(2);
int thirdDigitAsNumber = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(2,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are good. If I understand your question correctly you can also use  recursive method to print your numbers verticaly starting from last digit here is the recursive method that you can use:

```
public static void writeVertical(int number)
{
if(number <10)
 System.out.println(number);
else
{
 System.out.println(number%10);
 writeVertical(number/10);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you check my code and see if what i can do to optimize the code: http://pastebin.com/xrpKZixE

Comment: You need to post your code here so we can see what exactly you trying to do. If you need to print integer with the digits printed vertically, pass it to the recursive method above